# Redirect loop with clean install of DNN 7

Tags: redirect, dotnetnuke

I did a clean install of DNN 7 on my server and the installation went like expected.

But after clicking on visit website the pages just reloads the whole time in chrome.

In Firefox the pages loads but nothing more, clicking on any links results in a 404 not found error.

I have checked the portal alias that it has no trailing '/'

I have set the Trust level to full

The weird thing is I have another DNN deployment on the server working fine, no issues.

What could be causing this redirect loop?

Comment: Are there any entries in the error log? Look in the database as well as \Portals\_default\Logs folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the resolution for this, I had to enable `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` to the `<modules>` tag in the `web.config`.

Would be awesome if that wasn't needed as a manual thing.

IIS 7 on windows server 2008 R2, maybe someone can tell us why it is needed.